# PropertyInfo.SetValue throw System.NullReferenceException while setting value in C#

Tags: c#

```
     public class Expenses
        {
            public Category Category { get; set; }
        }

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

So I have these two classes. Now I want to convert the DataTable containing the records of Expense Class to List. I am using this method :

```
public static List<T> ConvertDataTable<T>(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<T> data = new List<T>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            T item = GetItem<T>(row);
            data.Add(item);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static T GetItem<T>(DataRow dr)
    {
        try
        {
            Type temp = typeof(T);
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

            foreach (DataColumn column in dr.Table.Columns)
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                    {
                        pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

[image: Here are the records fetched from the database]

[image: As you can see the Category class object is null and I want to fill the values of CategoryName and CategoryID that are in Category class]

Here are the records fetched from the database:
As you can see the Category class object is null and I want to fill the values of CategoryName and CategoryID that are in Category class.

So how can achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two option:

1- Remove `Category` property and `Inherit` it at `Expenses` class.

2- Try this:

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo pro in temp.GetProperties())
                    {
                        if(pro.PropertyType.IsClass && pro.PropertyType == typeof(Category))
                        {
                              Category subObj = Activator.CreateInstance<Category>();
                              foreach (PropertyInfo propertyin subObj.GetProperties())
                              {     
                                    if (dr[property.Name] != DBNull.Value) 
                                         property.SetValue(subObj , dr[property.Name], null);
                              }
                              pro.SetValue(obj, subObj , null);
                        }
                        if (pro.Name == column.ColumnName)
                        {
                             if (dr[pro.Name] != DBNull.Value) 
                                  pro.SetValue(obj, dr[column.ColumnName], null);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
```

And for NullReferenceException you must check value like this:

```
 if (dr[property.Name] != DBNull.Value)
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: In your first suggestion you told to "Remove Category property and Inherit it at Expenses class." but I have another class "Payment" and I have done the same as Category class. public class PaymentModes
    {
        public int PaymentModeID { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMode { get; set; }
    } and I have used this class in Expenses. So i can't inherit two classes at same time. So can you please tell me what should I do in this case?

Comment: @Arpit You can do like `B : A` and `C : B` But It's not good idea.I suggest second way.

Comment: Yeah I have used the second case and made if case for PaymentModes also. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: @Arpit You're Welcome.

Comment: Hi, @Hossein do you know how to achieve the same using Dapper?

Comment: @Arpit Hi.Please make new post.